# How computer stores images or videos as data, and where, can i make operations on it?

Tags: image, memory, store, pixel, bit

You know, computer stores images as channels and pixels in those channels. And pixel values are like "00110101" which fills 8 bits at memory. I want to know truly where that bits stored at memory, and how can i make operations on them.

Thanks!

Comment: What computer do you use - Windows? Linux? Mac? What operations do you want to do? Enlarge? Invert? Crop? Do you want to write programs to do it, or just run commands at the command line? Is performance/speed important?

Comment: @Mark Setchell I am using windows, i want to do a crop or enlarge operation, i want to write programs to do it, performance or speed are not such important but i dont want to fill much extra storage when doing operation. For example when enlarging, if i am enlarging for 4 bits i dont want to fill 32 bits of place at memory.

Comment: Why? You can buy gigabytes of RAM for a few $ ?

Comment: i want to do it for improving my programmer skills and get involved into graphic programming by an experiment, i want to learn graphic programming practically.

Comment: @Mark Setchell Do you have any suggestions to reach my goal, cropping, enlarging? I would be grateful, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the standard book is `Digital Image Processing` by `Gonzalez and Woods`.

Another book, where you can pick up the PDF for free is `Image Processing in C` by Dwayne Philips - [PDF here](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/BOOKS/PHILLIPS/cips2ed.pdf).

First, you need to get a decent C compiler and development system - personally I use Mac  OSX, but I guess you would want Visual Studio free edition on Windows.

Then you need to get started with some simple reading and writing of files and memory allocation. I would go with greyscale images of the NetPBM format - probably just `PGM` files - described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format) as they are the easiest. You can download the `NetPBM` programs and run them in a Windows Command Prompt and see how they work and try and implement them yourself in C. You can also download `ImageMagick` for Windows and try converting images from colour to greyscale and resizing them like this:

```
convert input.png -colorspace gray result.jpg

convert input.tif -resize 400x400 result.pgm
```

When you have got that, I would move on to colour PPM format and then maybe PNG and/or JPEG. Remember there are libraries for TIF/JPEG/PNG/BMP so don't be afraid to use them.

Finally, move on to displaying images yourself with Windows GDI etc.

Come back to StackOverflow if you get stuck - questions are free!

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr wildly different with different encodings/filesystems/os'es/drivers

Well that depends on the image format. BMP is one of the easier formats, details on what these files look like can be found on for instance [wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format)

And to answer "where its stored", it is stored on permanent storage (hardrive/ssd), where exactly depends on the filesystem (FAT/NTFS/EXT etc).

When an image is to be displayed, its read into memory, where it can be manipulated and through some apis this data can be put into a memory region specifically meant to display the current images on you screen.

Comment: If you want to experiment with manipulating images, i can recommend looking into pythons image library PIL/Pillow.